# Possible CSS inconsistensies in the new theme's Flagged Posts page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

On the Flagged Posts page, things seem a little odd. Like

- spam label
- <strike>some post title have backgrounds, others do not.</strike>

[image]

Comment: the ones with backgrounds are deleted posts, so that is by design?

Comment: As for the background of the titles - they're for deleted posts.

Comment: Ah I see, didn't know that.